# Как исправить Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function showMusic(mySRC) {
            alert('xyi');
            var music = window.parent.document.getElementById("music");
            music.style.display = "block";
            music.src = mySRC;
            var close = window.parent.document.getElementById("closeMusic");
            close.style.display = "block";
        }

</script>


<?php

                $dir_name = "albums";

                $openD = array_diff(scandir($dir_name), array('..', '.')); sort($openD);

                if (empty($openD)) {
                    echo '<img src="../../images/nothing.jpg"/>';
                    echo '<img src="../../images/to.jpg"/>';
                    echo '<img src="../../images/display.jpg"/>';
                }


                else {
                    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir_name) as $file) {
                        if ($file->isDot()) continue;

                        if ($file->isDir()) {
                            $path_to_music = 'albums/'.$file->getFilename().'/'.$file->getFilename().'.html';
                            echo '<img href="#" onclick="showMusic("'.$path_to_music.'");" src="albums/'.$file->getFilename().'/logo.jpg"/>';
                        }
                    }
                    unset($file);
                }

?>
```

не вызывается ф-я showMusic, т.к. не проходит alert,

браузер выдаёт Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

помогите пожалуйста

Comment: кавычки `onclick="showMusic("'.$path_to_music.'");"`

Comment: образуется вот такой вот код:
<img href="#" onclick="showMusic("albums/ccc/ccc.html");" src="albums/ccc/logo.jpg"/><img href="#" onclick="showMusic("albums/xxx/xxx.html");" src="albums/xxx/logo.jpg"/>

Comment: Где что не так?

Comment: я знаю. используются однородные кавычки, так что подумай какая кавычка закрывает какую во фразе `onclick="showMusic("albums/ccc/ccc.html");"`

Comment: понел, только как исправить?

Comment: Я поперебирал различные вариации кавычек

Comment: И что-то ничего не происходит

Comment: я не знаю синтаксис пыхи, так что тебе видней. в лоб решается так: `echo '<img href="#" onclick="showMusic('."'".$path_to_music."'".');" src="albums/'`

Comment: Есть, решено, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<img href="#" onclick="showMusic('."'".$path_to_music."'".');" src="albums/''.$file->getFilename().'/logo.jpg"/>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- echo '<img href="#" onclick="showMusic("'.$path_to_music.'");" src="albums/'.$file->getFilename().'/logo.jpg"/>';

+ echo '<img href="#" onclick="showMusic('."'".$path_to_music."'".');" src="albums/'.$file->getFilename().'/logo.jpg"/>';
```